# Adding additional information on product page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to add information in the additional information tab of the product page, but can't figure out from where it picks the data.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the product attributes in the backend.  You can configure existing and/or new product attributes and make them (optionally) show up in this section.  Make sure the attributes have "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" set to Yes.

Comment: This might be obvious, but you also need this attribute to be a part of attribute set, which was selected while creating this particular product, and then you need to insert a value of this attribute in product in admin.

Answer (score 1):

1)First create the attribute as per your requirement

2)Assign this to default attribute set then save.

3)go to attribute and make visible(from drop down)  your recently created attribute.

4)fill some value in the attribute(you created) for your selected product .
5)Again go to the attributes select your attribute then select yes or no to " Visible on Product View Page on Front-end " and "Used in Product Listing" depending your need.

If you need more help please inform..

Comment: if we do not set the value in particular attribute the it will showing "No"  against that attribute in product page